# Ebay REST API, using authorization_code with a console application

Tags: c#, .net, rest, ebay-api

I am currently using .NET Ebay SDK but started switching to using REST API.
I have a console application which runs in a background and does not need any user interaction.
I have got an application access token with `grant_type = client_credentials` but it support only

> "View public data from eBay"

[image]

Can I use `grant_type = authorization_code` with a console application without any user interaction?

I have also tried to generate a token form the browser

[image]

but when add this code into postman and try to get an access token, I get following error.

[image]

Comment: Were you using this SDK previously and you could obtain such a token with it? https://github.com/eBay/ebay-oauth-csharp-client

Comment: I suspect you want the auth flow for apps not users (users would mean user interaction that you don't want). According to the docs https://developer.ebay.com/api-docs/static/oauth-client-credentials-grant.html you at least need a different grant_type "client_credentials".

Comment: Unfortunately with app credentials only public data can be accessed.

Comment: @Ralf I can login to a browser 1 time but after that I would like to keep generating new tokens, I am not sure how long with token generated by the browser is valid for.

Comment: I assume you need then an access token for the refresh token you should also have now and use that for authorization. See https://developer.ebay.com/api-docs/static/oauth-refresh-token-request.html. For validity/expiry time you should simply look into the token. The jwt.io website has a decoder.

Comment: It is currently failing at getting access token as per my screenshot as well. Once I get the access token and a refresh token, next step would be to get a new token based on the refresh token but I am stuck at getting the first access token.